# How can I structure an IF statement inside of a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm hoping that what I have paints a clear enough picture of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT [Date]
    ,[ChargeCode]
    ,[ChargeDescription]
    ,[HHY_Qty]
    ,[PatPrice]
    , IF ISNUMERIC(HHY_Qty) AND ISNUMERIC(PatPrice)
        BEGIN   
            CAST(HHY_Qty AS INT) * CAST(PatPrice AS INT) AS ExtAmt
        END
        ELSE
            0 AS ExtAmt
        END
FROM [dbo].[ChargeDetails]
WHERE PatientNumber = '1271'
```

`HHY_Qty` and `PatPrice` are both `VARCHAR` types in a MSSQL database. They were created with a BULK INSERT from a very very very dirty CSV from an AS400 export. Here, I am trying to do some multiplication IF the fields are numeric values, otherwise ExtAmt should be 0. Is that possible? If not,, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(HHY_Qty) = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(PatPrice) = 1 THEN CAST(HHY_Qty AS INT) * CAST(PatPrice AS INT) ELSE 0 END AS ExtAmt
```

Comment: It seems to be complaining about the `ISNUMBERIC()`s - I'm getting this error: `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.`

Comment: @anwyatt Apparently ISNUMERIC returns an INT rather than a boolean, fixed the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Nailed it. I'll hit "accept" as soon as it lets me (6 minutes). Thanks!